# Xcode 6 beta to use as default xcode for my mac

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5

i have just installed the xcode 6 beta and uninstalled the xcode 5 version simply by moving to trash and empyting it. However whenever i try to use git and other terminal commands mac prompts me to install xcode, but i already have one installed, a beta version. How can i use that beta as a default xcode and use git and other features from it on terminal?

Comment: use `xcode-select` to switch b/w version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have set them as the same name and same foler as it saved in your computer? If you didn't know, try to open terminal and input these code "xcode-select -print-path". Check the displayed information and look whether it is as same as you setted. If wasn`t the same, change it (Input these code "xcode-select -switch ").